# How to set the frame of dynamically created button in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uibutton

I need to place a round button at bottom corner of my iPhone app. As of now for iPhone 5, below code is good but for other iPhones button comes in middle.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 260, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.setImage(UIImage(named:"dummy.jpg"), for: UIControlState.normal);
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(bankButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
```

So how do I set button fame dynamically so that it fits in all models of iPhone.
I want button.frame = CGRect(x: 260, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50) - its x and y to be set dynamically so that it is always in bottom corner.
I have attached the screenshot and this is how it looks.

[image]

Please guide on the same.

Comment: For the other views, do you use auto-layout? If yes you should use it for button too, if not, you should use auto-layout for all the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: 260, y: 500, width: 50, height: 50)
```

with

```
button.frame = CGRect(x:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 70 , y:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 70 , width: 50, height: 50)
```

OR use auto-layout

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

    button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant:-20),

    button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant:-20),
])
```

Comment: this line worked for me...button.frame = CGRect(x:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 70 , y:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 70 , width: 50, height: 50)

Answer (score 1):

In the storyboard,

> control + click on the Button.

Then drag to the bottom and click on **Bottom to safeArea**

Update, since you create it in `ViewDidLoad` you can use this extension to programmatically add a constraint to the bottom area and others ,

```
extension UIButton {

  var safeTopAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
    } else {
      return self.topAnchor
    }
  }

  var safeLeftAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
      return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor
    }else {
      return self.leftAnchor
    }
  }

  var safeRightAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
      return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor
    }else {
      return self.rightAnchor
    }
  }

  var safeBottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
      return self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
    } else {
      return self.bottomAnchor
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: button is  created at runtime, inside viewDidLoad()